# Same file displays differently based on HTML or PHP file extension

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have the following two files:

http://www.roostertooths.com/content/rvb/translations/test.html

http://www.roostertooths.com/content/rvb/translations/test.php

They both have the following character encoding:

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

The only difference between the two files is their file extension. However, when you view them in the browser, the accented characters display correctly on the html version, but are diamond question marks in the php version. This seems peculiar to me. Does anyone have some insight on how to make the php file display the characters correctly?

I have confirmed that copying the html file to a new php file reproduces the problem, so it's not that my ftp program is encoding them differently on upload. Further information:

```
file test.html
test.html: ISO-8859 HTML document text, with very long lines

file test.php
test.php: ISO-8859 HTML document text, with very long lines
```

Comment: "The only difference between the two files is their file extension" this is clearly not true

Comment: Your PHP document is setting the `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header whilst your HTML is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP default charset is probably set to "UTF-8".

The *only* difference between the files is the extension, but the extension means that the second file **is processed by PHP**, which adds a "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" header. And this has the precedence on the `meta` setting.

You need to change the default encoding in the PHP.INI file.

<sup>(Actually, I'd go UTF-8 everywhere, as in my experience that yields less troubles in the long run, but I suppose it depends on your setup and workflow).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. The site I'm doing this for actually has LOTS of plaintext files with special characters, so in this particular case it's better for me to clear the default php encoding (I'm using `ini_set( 'default_charset', "" );` in the settings file). I can now stop manually going bald.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the headers, you can see that the PHP file added the charset to the `Content-Type` header:

[image: PHP file header]

But the HTML one did not:

[image: HTML file header]